# How to capture video from a video device on mobile using HTML Code or javascript

Tags: javascript, html, webcam

Ideally what i want to do is to capture and records video on my website but be iphone and mobile friendly so users with mobile can save a video on their mobile and upload it into my site.  I need to be able to take webcam input from a camera on any device sush as mobile show a live preview , record and play back . then upload it. I dont think any flash would help since iphone doesnt read flash. I tried few examples of html5 http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/  but it doesnt work on iphone or mobile devices. any help would be appreciated

Comment: The HTML5Rocks article mentioned the `HTML Media Capture` standard which you can use on mobile, see my answer @benji_r

Answer (score 4):

The `HTML Media Capture` standard is a HTML only solution that works great on all mobile browsers. For recording video use:

`<input type="file" accept="video/*" capture >`

Here's how the above code looks on iOS8:
[image: HTML Media Capture on iOs]
Image courtesy of https://blog.addpipe.com/the-new-video-recording-prompt-for-media-capture-in-ios9/

The only issue is that you'll get .mov videos from iOS devices and .mp4/.3gp videos from Android devices. Those .mov files won't play on Android.

`HTML Media Capture` is a mobile only solution, it is not implemented in desktop browsers.

Answer (score 0):

with the phonegap framework you can do it

```
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.5.0/phonegap_media_capture_capture.md.html#Capture
```

Comment: hi, I am looking into it now, Thank you very much